# ArrayFormula for SUMPRODUCT of mismatched arrays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a grid of hours and an array of rates.
I'd like the array `E2:E10` to be the `sumproduct` of the hours and the transposed RATES array.

Can someone help with the `ArrayFormula`?

I can easily do `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2),$I$2:$I$5)` for `E2` but it'd be more elegant to do an `ArrayFormula` that does the whole column if possible.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `BYROW` and `LAMBDA` there is no need for `ArrayFormula()`:

```
=BYROW(A2:D10,LAMBDA(a,SUMPRODUCT(a,TRANSPOSE($I$2:$I$5))))
```

[image]